# CodeDom: How to add reference with Alias

Tags: c#, codedom

Is there any way I can specify alias name for an assembly while adding it to the ReferencedAssemblies collection of CompilerParameters ?

Basically when I compile the code using CodeDom, it should imitate below csc command line.

csc /r:Infra=Infra.dll /r:ultra:altra.dll